# ridiculously high storage usage in iPhone 6+

Tags: ios, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I'm working (helping out) on an iOS app. On most devices the app's stabilized storage use is within `60-80MB`. The same app (and same revision) on the iPhone 6+ starts using ***Gigabytes*** of data within minutes ... to the point of filling up the storage and I can't even run the app from XCode anymore. I've only been able to get it on the iPhone 6 once, but it's a regular occurrence on the 6+. I've also tried on a range of other devices from 5th gen iPod touch to the iPhone 5 and no other device goes over the 80MB.

The only portion of code that uses a significant amount of storage is the image caching, which caches the (static) images downloaded from the server keyed on the image id. Then again this code is (or seems to be) working fine on other devices. It is also a portion of the codebase that hasn't changed in a while.

Can anyone think of a reason why this issue is only seen on the iPhone6+ (and to a **much** lower extent the iPhone6)?

Comment: Can you post some of the image caching code?

Comment: Use. Instruments! That's what it's for.

Comment: @matt Instruments just seems to crash.

Comment: Well darn! But look - you haven't provided any code, so how can we be expected to help? You've already got a suspect as the cause; start debugging. I'd suggest you simply comment out the suspect code (stubbing in some kind of substitute if necessary) and see if the problem is solved. If it is, that was it.

Comment: I'm already doing that, but I'm an Android developer and not very versed at iOS dev. Now the File Activity instruments tells me the device (iPhone 6, already at 1.2GB) does not support this instrument.

Comment: Read this guide, I solved related issues with images taking up too much space with this http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode  you likely need to look at the allocation instruments

Comment: Just to confirm, you're talking about flash drive storage rather than RAM, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that malloc stack logging was enabled and not set to compact. It logged every single allocation made by the app and it was the log file that grew so large.

As to why it only occured on the iPhone6 and iPhone6+, I still don't have an answer.

The problematic file was `stack-logs.773.1006c8000.REDACTED.wmQj2k.index`. It grew to 700MB almost right after login.

Much thanks to @jrturton because his answer really lead to this.

Comment: Oh, well done! You should probably accept your own answer, though, since it has the actual cause in it.

Comment: @jrturton I'll take it ... but only because you insisted :) Thanks a lot for your help. Thanks to all for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a solution, since it's impossible to know what's happening, but you should look at the following:

- Is this reproducible on the simulator? (file system is easier to view)
- Does the storage get freed when the app is deleted?
- Can you see the data in the device organiser in xcode (they keep moving it, but somewhere you can plug in the device, see the app, and then see the file sandbox for that app)
- What data is it? This should give you a clue as to its origin
- is there a set of actions in the app that kick off the problem?

If this works, you should get a clue as to the offending code. Then, update your question, unless the solution is obvious!

Comment: Haven't tried the simulator yet. Storage is freed up once the app is deleted.I'll check the device organizer for the data. I suspect it's the image cache, but as I've said above that code has worked without this issue for years and over many iterations. There doesn't seem to be a specific action that makes it go storage hungry. The app doesn't do much while the user is not logged in. Once the user logs in and navigates through the app the storage piles up.

Comment: Upon inspection of one of the files --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/27370445/675750